# Name of futuristic novel with humanoids and a starship

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I remember a novel I read back in the nineties that involved a futuristic war between two opposing humanoid factions that have settled various planets in the solar system.

I remember there being aliens as well, but I'm fairly certain they weren't involved in the conflict.

I believe one of the factions piloted a starship named after a famous person in history.

Unless I'm confusing the story with a different one, I'm pretty sure several of the humanoids joined together in a massive orgy to celebrate the banishment of some kind of spirits.

Does anyone remember the name of this story?

Comment: There's a couple of things in there that put me in mind of Stephen Lawhead's Empyrion duology - does that ring any bells?

Comment: No aliens in Empyrion, and I'm pretty sure no orgy (in the strict sense) either.

Answer (score 3):

### Peter F Hamilton's "[The Night's Dawn Trilogy](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwid4Ziq7rjKAhUC6RQKHeI9BP4QFgg0MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fseries%2F43318-night-s-dawn&usg=AFQjCNF90K8zTRUPzXdzNNMsFIF9dzJ_Mw&sig2=uXim7gEleafpsCtVdcJAGQ)"?

Is it possibly this?

Containing the books *The Reality Dysfunction*, *The Neutronium Alchemist* and *The Naked God*

Written between 1996 & 1999

There are two human factions the Adamists and the Edenists, though they are spread out over the galaxy not just the solar system. It opens with an attack on an asteroid mining facility using banned anti-matter bombs.

> *... involved a futuristic war between two opposing humanoid factions that have settled various planets in the solar system*

There are a number of alien species that are around the periphery of the story but not involved in the actual conflict between the humans.

> *... remember there being aliens as well, but I'm fairly certain they weren't involved in the conflict*

One of the protagonists pilots a ship called the ***Lady Macbeth.***

> *I believe one of the factions piloted a starship named after a famous person in history*

Dead spirits inhabit the bodies of humans and the main plot point of the story revolves around this possession and the quest to end it. The leader of the possessed is the spirit of *Al Capone*.

> *I'm pretty sure several of the humanoids joined together in a massive orgy to celebrate the banishment of some kind of spirits*

There is copious amounts of sex throughout the three books so an orgy would not be out of place.

Each book is a tome containing many hundreds of pages.

Comment: "main plot point of the film"? Wow, I only know the books. They made a movie? :-)

Comment: @Hothie oops fixed - any movie would have to be movieS for these books. About 7 of them at least I would think

Comment: At least the german version was 6 Books with around 1000 pages each I think. The 7th book was a short story collection in the same universe. It would be impossible to fit it in one movie without crippling it. And it would be difficult to make several movies of it (who can plan and sell 7 sequel movies with cliffhangers). Perhaps it will make a good TV series.

Comment: I read it in three books each of which had to be over 1500 pages. It would have to be a long running TV series to make any sense. That said I would rather see his commonwealth series make it to our screens first as this is my favourite of the two

Comment: @Cearon O'Flynn The Lady Macbeth was Calvert's Adamist (non-organic tech) starship. You're thinking of the Voidhawk Oenone captained by Syrinx.

Comment: @Harabeck thanks! Fixed it’s been a while

Answer (score -1):

Aside from the aliens this almost sounds like the [Bio of a Space Tyrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bio_of_a_Space_Tyrant) series by Piers Anthony.